# evaluate user input as parameter in string using NCalc

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to prompt the user for a number and then use `NCalc` to evaluate and solve formula

```
string a = Console.ReadKey().ToString();
Expression e = new Expression("2 + [a] * 5"); 
object x = e.Evaluate();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

this gives me error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "Expression"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to pass parameter for your literal value `a`;

```
string a = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();     // add KeyChar
Expression e = new Expression("2 + [a] * 5"); 
e.Parameters["a"] = a;                               // don't forget this line
object x = e.Evaluate();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

one more thing,

```
string a = Console.ReadKey().ToString();
// yields a string value: System.ConsoleKeyInfo 
// and not the number you typed.
```

so much better to use

```
string a = Console.ReadLine()
// or
string a = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();     // KeyChar
```

Comment: that gives an exception "Input string was not in a correct format."  and it point to this line- "object x = e.Evaluate();"

Comment: @Avi.S. try it again, it has something to do with `Console.ReadKey().ToString();`, it should be `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();`

Comment: much better if you use `string a = Console.ReadLine();`